# Quicksorting integer array practice

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort

So I have this array `{3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5}`

I'm using median-of-three method to get the pivots.

So in this case the median here is between left, middle, right: 3,9,5. So it's 5

First thing I do is make sure the pivot is on the leftmost.
Now I keep the numbers less than 5 in the left and move the numbers greater to the right most of the array. Final result is: `{3,1,4,1,2,3|5|5,9,6,5}`

Now quicksort the left and right subarrays.

`{3,1,4,1,2,3}` has median 3 and after rearranging I get `{1,1,2,3,4}`

`{5,9,6,5}` has median 5 and I get `{5,5,9,6}` as the result of sorting equal and greater numbers to the right. But this subarray didn't sort like the first subarray. It would only work if median was 6. So where did it going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You're only done when the subarray size is 1. You can't just stop after an arbitrary number of iterations.

Comment: So you're saying that you have to keep rearranging numbers with the lesser value in left and greater values in the right until the subarray sizes becomes 1 each?

Comment: Yes, you need to sort the subarrays recursively.

Comment: One last thing. Are the medians/pivots pushed to the rightmost spot before the lesser values are placed to the left and greater values to the right?

Comment: Yes, this is a common practice (although it is completely equivalent to push it to the leftmost spot). It's easier to partition the array that way. If you place it in the rightmost spot of the subarray, you can switch it with the first element in the > or >=-section to restore the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

You have to sort the right subarray of `{|5|5,9,6}` (or `{5|5|,9,6}`) again. The median is 6 and the result will be `{5,6,9}` (or `{6,9}`).

Also note that naive Quicksort with many duplicate keys can degrade to quadratic time complexity. There are ways to detect keys equal to the pivot and exclude them from the subarrays that are sorted recursively.